# C# Covariance for EventHandler Delegate

Tags: c#, generics, event-handling, covariance

C# does not like the following snippet:

```
public delegate void CustomEventHandler<out T>(object? sender, CustomEventArgs<T> e);

public class CustomEventArgs<T> : EventArgs
{
    public IReadOnlyList<T> Items { get; }
}
```

I want to make the event handler delegate covariant, but it seems that the covariance is incompatible with a concrete class, even if the concrete class uses a generic type only to instantiate an interface that is also covariant. How can the delegate be made to be covariant? I specifically don't want to drop the generic T on the CustomEventArgs class.

Comment: Remove the `out` keyword and it compiles. If you need to keep it for some reason, please explain the overall problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: How about creating a covariant `ICustomEventArgs<T>` interface? `CustomEventArgs` can still be a class, which implements `ICustomEventArgs`. Also, you seem to imply that `IList<T>` is covariant. *It is not.* How about using `IReadOnlyList<T>` instead? You would also need to remove the setter for this to safely be covariant.

Comment: @JohnWu I'm specifically trying to make the event handler delegate covariant so that I can use covariance in some other parts of my project.

Comment: @Sweeper thanks for those clarifications. You are absolutely correct about IList<T>, that was a stupid oversight on my part. I have updated to reflect that. I will admit to having not thought very far down the ICustomEventArgs<out T> route because that seems somehow ridiculously messy to me.  Is that the usual approach to situations like these?